# Writing about a paper that won't be published (but got accepted) in my resume

Tags: publications, ethics, cv

(I believe my question is not a duplicate, I've seen all others related to this.)

I'm an undergrad and I need to make a resume to apply for jobs (in industry) including a paper that we submitted to a conference. The paper got accepted, but we weren't able to get a visa. So, the paper will go unpublished. (We plan to submit it elsewhere, but that'll take time)

Is it correct to write (in my resume) that I have an accepted paper? If it is, can I just mention it as "accepted"? In that case is it unethical to *not* mention that I know it won't be published?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess this may depend on the field, but at least from my experience, I would expect the conference to still publish the paper in this situation.  It seems very strange for them to “un-accept” it just because of visa difficulties.

Comment: The conference website mentions that papers won't be published on no-show. It's conducted by IEEE, a famous organization in some engineering disciplines.

Comment: Yes, we spoke to the conference organizers. They denied a skype talk (also mentioned on their website) and said there's no way they can accommodate.

Comment: Contact the session chair, let him know the whole situation. If everything goes well, you need to arrange alternate speaker/presenter who are going to attend the conference. I did same when I was a student and I had to provide the proof for decline of VISA. I saw many such presentation in several flagship IEEE conferences.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll talk to my PI and see if that can be done. But I'm still waiting eagerly for answers on how I could explain my situation in the resume.

Comment: It should be OK to include the paper in your resume with the annotation "accepted for [name and date of conference] but not presented because of visa denial".